# How to call a function in javascript object literal notation declaration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, rickshaw

I am new in javascript, my question is how they are calling javascript (object literal nation) in following code. I didn't see `defaults : function($super)` is called in following code.

I have taken following code from [horizon.d3linechart.js
 from openstack](https://github.com/openstack/horizon/blob/master/horizon/static/horizon/js/horizon.d3linechart.js#L426-435). Alert in defaults: function is calling many times but I searched the code but didn't find this function where they called. Please tell me how these function called.

```
Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.StaticAxes =   Rickshaw.Class.create(Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.Line, {
  //alert("HJ1");
  name: 'StaticAxes',
  defaults: function($super) {
   alert("13 => This is repeated many time. Rickshaw.Graph.Renderer.StaticAxes");
    return Rickshaw.extend($super(), {
      xMin: undefined,
      xMax: undefined,
      yMin: undefined,
      yMax: undefined
    });
  },
  domain: function($super) {
    //alert("HJ");
    var ret = $super();
    var xMin, xMax;
    // If y axis wants to have static range, not based on data
    if (this.yMin !== undefined && this.yMax !== undefined) {
      ret.y = [this.yMin, this.yMax];
    }
    // If x axis wants to have static range, not based on data
    if (this.xMin !== undefined && this.xMax !== undefined) {
      xMin = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(this.xMin);
      xMin = xMin.getTime() / 1000;
      xMax = d3.time.format.utc('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').parse(this.xMax);
      xMax = xMax.getTime() / 1000;
      ret.x = [xMin, xMax];
    }
      return ret;
  }
```

Comment: Instead alert() use Firebug, Luke.

Comment: I guess these functions are called from inside the `Rickshaw` add-on whatever this might be. You only assign a (anonymous) function to the defaults option, you are not calling it anywhere in your code

Comment: @devnull69 I think you are right...

Comment: You'll want to look at the source of `Rickshaw.Class.create` to see what happens with that object and its `default` method.